# Perl hung when asked for count ++

Tags: perl

I'm writing a code for me to extract some information from the log.
But each time I run, the Perl hangs and my text file doesn't increase in size a.k.a hang.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "What are the month of logs you're looking to start?\n";
$opt1 = <>;
chomp($opt1);
print "What are the month of logs you're looking to end search?\n";
$opt2 = <>;
chomp($opt2);
print "What are the day of logs you're looking to start?\n";
$opt3 = <>;
chomp($opt3);
print "What are the day of logs you're looking to end search?\n";
$opt4 = <>;
chomp($opt4);

for($month=$opt1;$month<$opt2;$month++) 
{
my $mymonth = sprintf '%02d', $month;

for($myDay=$opt3;$myDay<$opt4;$myDay++)
{
my $myDay2 = sprintf '%02d', $myDay;

#---------------------------------------------------------
# SET YESTERDAY DATE
# ----------------------
my $now = defined $_[0] ? $_[0] : time;
my $then = $now - 60*60*24*$myDay;
my $ndst = (localtime $now)[8] > 0;
my $tdst = (localtime $then)[8] > 0;

$then - ($tdst - $ndst) * 60 * 60 ;

my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime($then);
my $yesterday ="16".$mymonth.$myDay2;
my $today =$yesterday;
print $today."\n";

my $count100 = 0;
my $count200 = 0;
my $count500 = 0;


print "\nCount total charging 200, 500 DN".$today.".log\n";
open (textfile,"C:\\VasBoss\\Log\\didi\\DN".$today.".log");

open (MYFILE, ">> 2TK.txt");
open (MYFILE2, ">> 5TK.txt");
open (MYFILE3, ">> 1TK.txt");

while (<textfile>)
{
($MobileNo,$SubscriberID,$Shortcode,$Telco,$MO_time,$MO_id,$TransactionType,$Language,$Content,$checkprice,$ChargeStatus,$Contentmsg,$ChatDisabled)= split(/,/);
($date,$MobileNo1)  = split(/\>/,$MobileNo);
($MobileNo2,$MobileNo3)  = split(/\=/,$MobileNo1);
($Content1,$Content2)  = split(/\>/,$Content);
if(($checkprice =~ /200$/i ) && ($Content2 =~ /=0$/i))
{       
    print MYFILE $MobileNo3."\n";
    $count200++;

}
if(($checkprice =~ /500$/i ) && ($Content2 =~ /=0$/i))
{       
    print MYFILE2 $MobileNo3."\n";
    $count500++;
}

if(($checkprice =~ /100$/i ) && ($Content2 =~ /=0$/i))
{       
    print MYFILE3 $MobileNo3."\n";
    $count100++;
}
}
print $count100;
print $count200;
print $count500;
sleep;
}
}
```

Edit , I've found the solution.
I've found that the global explicit variable clashing my compilation.

Comment: `$then - ($tdst - $ndst) * 60 * 60 ;` looks like a typo.

Comment: Always use `use warnings;` and `use strict;` in Perl code.

Comment: You don't seem to have `use strict;` or `use warnings;` in use.  You aren't explicitly checking file open errors, nor are you using `use autodie;`.  Those are potential problems.  Basic debugging suggests you should be printing out lines as they're read, and then fields after they're split, to make sure your program is getting what you expect.

Comment: `textfile` is a wrong filehandle name in `open` line. It should be `TEXTFILE` or better lexical filehandle `$textfile`.

Comment: @serenesat: `textfile` is a old-style non-lexical filehandle (like `STDERR`, `STDOUT`, `STDIN`), but legitimate.  Conventionally, they're capitalized, but that's convention, not necessity — AFAICR.

Comment: @Mat, it's giving the results i want thou.

Comment: @serenesat , ty for the heads up

Comment: @JonathanLeffler,i'll give it a try. a sec

Comment: Any further commentary is hard — what you show is not an MCVE ([MCVE]), and you've not shown any (minimized) sample data that triggers the problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, ty mate will do better. Now when i use strict, too many explicit.. need to add my. but literally the count++ just hang.

Comment: @Jeeva'sPanorama: that line doesn't do anything. If that's what you want, fine, but you might as well remove it.

Comment: @Mat, true actually i kept there for some equation of the time for logging issue

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem will be this :

```
sleep;
```

Because from the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sleep.html) :

> Causes the script to sleep for (integer) EXPR seconds, or forever if no argument is given.

But whilst we are at it:

- Use `strict` and `warnings`
- 3 argument `open` with lexical filehandles is better style.
- Check your return codes from `open`.

Comment: thx for the effort. But I think i just found the warnings for the perl

Use of uninitialized value in print at test.pl line 82, <textfile> line 46256.
Use of uninitialized value in print at test.pl line 83, <textfile> line 46256.
Use of uninitialized value in print at test.pl line 84, <textfile> line 46256.

Literally when end line i'm printing.. It doesn't show anything.

Comment: I think i found the solution

Answer (score 2):

```
print $count100;   <-- You think it hung before here,
print $count200;
print $count500;
sleep;             <-- but it hung here as requested.
```

You didn't see the output of the `print` statements because STDOUT starts off line-buffered<sup>[1]</sup>, meaning it will only send the text to `print` when it encounters a newline.

To force any pending output to be sent, add the following before `sleep`.

```
select()->flush();
```

But you probably meant to print a newline, so what you should really add is the following:

```
print "\n";
```

Note that `sleep` without arguments sleeps indefinitely<sup>[2]</sup>, so I'm not sure why you're using that at all.

---

1. When connected to a terminal. It starts off block-buffered otherwise.
2. Or until a signal comes in if you have signal handlers defined

Answer (score -3):

This is the solution.
I replace the variable my count100 =0; to count100 =0; then it worked and it's giving the results i wanted

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;

print "What are the month of logs you're looking to start?\n";
my $opt1 = <>;
chomp($opt1);
print "What are the month of logs you're looking to end search?\n";
my $opt2 = <>;
chomp($opt2);
print "What are the day of logs you're looking to start?\n";
my $opt3 = <>;
chomp($opt3);
print "What are the day of logs you're looking to end search?\n";
my $opt4 = <>;
chomp($opt4);

for($month=$opt1;$month<$opt2;$month++) 
{
    my $mymonth = sprintf '%02d', $month;

for($myDay=$opt3;$myDay<$opt4;$myDay++)
{
    my $myDay2 = sprintf '%02d', $myDay;

#---------------------------------------------------------
# SET YESTERDAY DATE
# ----------------------
my $now = defined $_[0] ? $_[0] : time;
my $then = $now - 60*60*24*$myDay;
my $ndst = (localtime $now)[8] > 0;
my $tdst = (localtime $then)[8] > 0;

$then - ($tdst - $ndst) * 60 * 60 ;

my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime($then);
my $yesterday ="16".$mymonth.$myDay2;
my $today =$yesterday;
print $today."\n";

$count100 = 0;
$count200 = 0;
$count500 = 0;


print "\nCount total charging 200, 500 DN".$today.".log\n";
open (textfile,"C:\\VasBoss\\Log\\didi\\DN".$today.".log");

open (MYFILE, ">> 2TK.txt");
open (MYFILE2, ">> 5TK.txt");
open (MYFILE3, ">> 1TK.txt");

while (<textfile>)
{
    ($MobileNo,$SubscriberID,$Shortcode,$Telco,$MO_time,$MO_id,$TransactionType,$Language,$Content,$checkprice,$ChargeStatus,$Contentmsg,$ChatDisabled)= split(/,/);
    ($date,$MobileNo1)  = split(/\>/,$MobileNo);
    ($MobileNo2,$MobileNo3)  = split(/\=/,$MobileNo1);
    ($Content1,$Content2)  = split(/\>/,$Content);
    if(($checkprice =~ /200$/i ) && ($Content2 =~ /=0$/i))
    {       
        print MYFILE $MobileNo3."\n";
         $count200++;

    }
    if(($checkprice =~ /500$/i ) && ($Content2 =~ /=0$/i))
    {       
        print MYFILE2 $MobileNo3."\n";
         $count500++;
    }

    if(($checkprice =~ /100$/i ) && ($Content2 =~ /=0$/i))
    {       
        print MYFILE3 $MobileNo3."\n";
        $count100++;
    }
}

}

}

print $count100."\n";
print $count200."\n";
print $count500."\n";
```